# CSS Transition Animation Content Overlapping

Tags: html, css, animation

I would like to ask about, I have made some animation in my website named bubbles. Basically what it does is just to rotate and float some boxes within a given space in the defined content. But i have a problem which is the animated content overlaps with the main content i wanted to display. For example I have `<form>` inputs but whenever the animation floats to the input boxes, the boxes is unclickable. I would like to send those animation to the background so that it wont obstruct my main UI. How should i do that?

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7rtp8mg1/) site to the sample code. You can try clicking on the input forms when the squares float on it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the css-class:

```
pointer-events:none;
```

To all of your animated items, that should do the trick.

Comment: Keep in mind that z-index-ing at a lower or negative value can lead to your animation appearing in the background of any "positioned" item.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion... What I did is i added `pointer-events:none;` into my root `.bg-bubbles li` class and it works like a charm...

Answer (score 0):

Set `z-index` of `.bg-bubbles` to `-1`. Cheers